# How to mock property of a service class in angular (Jasmine/Karma)

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine, spy

I am trying to mock **currentOrganizationMessageSource** from my service but getting getting following error:

*this.OrganizationService.currentOrganizationMessageSource.subscribe is not a function*

I tried to use spyOnProperty and than I get *currentOrganizationMessageSource is not a property*

Class:

```
export class OrganizationEditComponent implements OnInit {

  feedback: any = {};
  appOrgs: OrganizationDataModel;
  organizationLocationTableTitle: string;


  constructor(
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private orgService: OrganizationService) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadOrganisation();
  }

  private loadOrganisation()
  {
    this.orgService.currentOrganizationMessageSource.subscribe(
      org => this.appOrgs = org);
      this
      .route
      .params
      .pipe(
        map(p => p.id),
        switchMap(id => {
          if (id === 'new') { return of(this.appOrgs); }
          if (id != null) {
            return this.orgService.findByOrganizationsId(id);
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe(orgs => {
          this.orgService.changeMessage(orgs);
          this.appOrgs = orgs;
          this.feedback = {};
        },
        err => {
          this.feedback = {type: 'warning', message:'Error'};
        }
      );
  }
```

Service:

```
export class OrganizationService {

  private OrganizationMessageSource = new BehaviorSubject( new OrganizationDataModel());
  currentOrganizationMessageSource = this.OrganizationMessageSource.asObservable();


  changeMessage(appOrganization: appOrganizationDataModel) {
    this.appOrganizationMessageSource.next(appOrganization);
  }
}
```

Test spec class:

```
fdescribe('OrganizationEditComponent', () => {
  let component: OrganizationEditComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OrganizationEditComponent>;
  let activatedRoutes: any = {};


  beforeEach(async(async () => {
    const OrganizationService: OrganizationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('OrganizationService', ['currentOrganizationMessageSource']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ OrganizationEditComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoutes },
        { provide: Router, useValue: {url: ''}},
        { provide: OrganizationService, useValue: OrganizationService },
      ],      
      imports: [ FormsModule ] ,
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    // component.ngOnInit();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrganizationEditComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  function givenServicesAreMocked() {
    const spy = TestBed.get(OrganizationService);
    // let mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj(OrganizationService, ['currentOrganizationMessageSource']);
    // mockService.currentOrganizationMessageSource.and.returnValue('');
    // spyOnProperty(OrganizationService, "OrganizationMessageSource").and.returnValue([]);
    // OrganizationService.currentOrganizationMessageSource = () => {
    //   return [];
    // };
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `spyOn(component.orgService, 'currentkhojiOrganizationMessageSource').and.returnValue(of({}))` returnValue should be Observable notice `of` also I guess you need to make `orgService` public in your constructor

Comment: @KamranKhatti firstly if a directly refer as component.orgService by making it public than my test class says that orgService does not exist in class if I replace component.orgService with mocked value (let orgService: any ={ } ) than I get  currentOrganizationMessageSource() method does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea but you can't mock properties with `createSpyObj`, just methods.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
// the 2nd argument is for public methods, not properties
    const OrganizationService: OrganizationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('OrganizationService', ['changeMessage']);
// attach currentOrganizationMesageSource as a property to OrganizationService and mock the value
OrganizationService.currentOrganizationMessageSource = of(/* Mock the value here */);
// keep everything else the same
```

That should hopefully work.

You also need to properly mock the `ActivatedRoute` and the `Router`. For the router, just add `RouterTestingModule` to the `imports` array. It's provided by Angular and helps when testing component/services that inject the router.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this createMockService method, based on  [ts-mockery lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mockery)

```js
import { Mock, Mockery } from 'ts-mockery';

interface Stub {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export function createMockService<T>(service: Type<T>, stubs?: Stub) {
  Mockery.configure('jasmine');
  const mockedFunctions = stubs ? stubs : {};
  if (!stubs) {
    for (const key in service.prototype) {
      mockedFunctions[key] = () => null;
    }
  }
  return {
    provide: service,
    useValue: Mock.of<Type<T>>(mockedFunctions)
  };
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SomeModule, OtherModule],
      declarations: [SomeComponent, MockComponent(OtherComponent)],
      providers: [createMockService(OrganizationService)]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

This has nothing to do with your problem but note the MockComponent from [ng-mocks lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) which is a proper way to encapsulated your karma tests, thus enabling testing only for your component, without using [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA] which is kinda bad practice.

Here is an exemple where you need the returned value mocked using the of rxjs operator

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
const RESULT = [{id: 1, name:"test"},{id: 2, name:"toto"}];
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SomeModule, OtherModule],
      declarations: [SomeComponent, MockComponent(OtherComponent)],
      providers: [createMockService(OrganizationService, { yourMethod: () => of(RESULTS) })]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Your mocked service will always be very easy to mock that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `of` operator.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Define orgService before use:

```
 let orgService : KhojiOrganizationService;
```

add this to beforeach:

```
orgService= TestBed.get(KhojiOrganizationService);
```

Test Case:

```
it('should fetch data', () => {
   spyOn(orgService, 'currentkhojiOrganizationMessageSource').and.returnValue(of('test Data'));
   component.ngOnInit();
   expect(component.appOrgs).toEqual('test Data');
});
```

As an example i am passing `string` inside `of` operator. You can pass `Object`/ `array of objects` inside that and change the expectation as per your datamodel.

Comment: Actually this service KhojiOrganizationService has another service in its constructor. so when I define TestBad like this   let service: KhojiOrganizationService = new KhojiOrganizationService(http); and  orgService= TestBed.get(service); then I get following error  Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[[object Object]]:

Comment: Define it like this  let orgService : KhojiOrganizationService; and then use `TestBed` as mentioned on the answer.